# Unity-made WP8.1 app crashes at startup with TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1

I made a simple game in Unity3D and created a Windows Phone build. However, when I try to run the game, it crashes immediately with `TypeInitializationException`.

The crash happens in the generated `MainPage.xaml.cs` file, in the constructor:

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    var bridge = new UnityBridge();
    UnityApp.SetBridge(bridge);
    InitializeComponent();
    bridge.Control = DrawingSurfaceBackground; // <--- This line = crash
}
```

The exact error goes like this:

```
TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code

An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in WinRTBridge.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge' threw an exception.
```

Why does this happen? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a `TypeInitializationException` is created and passed a reference to the exception thrown by the type's class initializer. The `InnerException` property of `TypeInitializationException` holds the underlying exception. Try to log this property and see what actually cause a exception. Other way around it would be to wrap it in a `try{}catch(TypeInitializationException)` block .